# Class with non-default constructor

Tags: java, class, constructor

I'm trying to create a LinearNode class with a non default contractor but passing the two arguments. I tried this but I'm getting an error. Any idea why?

```
public class LinearNode<T> (T elem, LinearNode<T> node){
        private LinearNode<T> next = node;
        private T element = elem;
    }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have mixed the constructor with the class definition. The constructor is a special member function and should be defined more or less like a method (with no return type and the same name as the class).

```
public class LinearNode<T> {
    private LinearNode<T> next;
    private T element;

    LinearNode(T elem, LinearNode<T> node) {
        next = node;
        element = elem;
    }
}
```

Comment: correct answer, but could use some explanation. This site is not meant to be a place to have people write code for you.

Comment: Ok, I thought the example was so small that it explained it self. But you are right.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have `(arguments)` with class declaration

And also

you can't specify access specifier `private` for local variables

Answer (score 0):

Your constructor declaration needs to be separate from your class declaration. Like so:

```
public class LinearNode<T>{
    private LinearNode<T> next;
    private T element;
    LinearNode<T>(T elem, LinearNode<T> node){
        next = node;
        element = elem;
   }
}
```